# How do I integrate Machine.Specifications with ReSharper 6?

Tags: resharper, mspec

I'm using ReSharper 6 and I'm trying to get it to pick up my MSpec tests in the Resharper test runner. Unfortunately I can't seem to get this to work.

I have copied the MSpec dll files (Machine.Specifications.dll and Machine.Specifications.ReSharperRunner.5.1.dll) to the ReSharper plugin directory but it does not seem to find the plugin. When opening the test runner and refreshing no tests are picked up.

I do realize that the test runner plugin is for version 5.1 but ReSharper should at least find the tests in my solution, even if it is not able to run them using the 5.1 runner?

Any suggestions on how to get this to work?

Comment: I took a look at the code base for the existing Resharper plugin and tried to compile it against Resharper 6's plugin model. The plugin support has really changed a lot as Chrixian said. Whole interfaces/classes are gone, changed, and/or no longer inherit from the their previous base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resharper team just post (July 20th, 2011) a solution about the integration of MSpec in Resharper 6.

[Head over there](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/07/machinespecifications-for-resharper-6-now-available/)

Comment: Thanks, I experimented with the early versions during development but now it seems to be stable and working. Tried it and all seems good.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Machine.Specifications but I do know you won't be able to use a 5.x compiled plugin with 6.0 because the DLL's have changed **a lot**

You can run Visual Studio with "devenv.exe /ReSharper.Internal" flag to enable the internal debug menu in Resharper, that might give you a starting point if you were to download MSpec source and attempt to compile with the Resharper 6.0 DLL's

Comment: Yeah I thought the plugin might not work but I wanted to give it a shot. Thought it would maybe pick up the Mspec dll though. Good idea with compiling against the new R#, will give it a try.

Comment: Compiling won't suffice as the APIs have changed quite a bit. We're working on support for ReSharper 6.0.

Comment: Any news on ReSharper 6 integartion? MSpec integration R# 5 was the killer feature for me and lack of this feature in v6 is stopping me from upgrading :(

Comment: @lucisferre started working on ReSharper 6 integration and told me he got it partially working. Right now he and I don't have much time working on it, but you may check his fork at GitHub: https://github.com/lucisferre/machine.specifications/tree/resharper6